# FileField Database

Tags: 7, database, files

I like the idea of using a field within a database to hold a file.

Is it possible to store files within a database instead of within folders with Drupal 7?

My current setup is Drupal 7, Ubuntu Server 10.10/11.04, MySql, Apache2. I could switch to IIS if need be (I like Ubuntu for test server since it's lightweight and more flexible, but work is mainly windows servers... so I could go either way)

Comment: What specific usecases are you trying to solve by storing files in db column? There are many disadvantages to that approach:

Comment: Everything else is kept in the database. It just seems logical and easier to me to have the data kept as a "blob" field in my planned setup. That would keep all "data" in one place (files are data too). My setup will have one possible file per content type (that isn't reused elsewhere). I'm working on file management as well, but I figured I'd explore this avenue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [dbfm](http://drupal.org/project/dbfm) module, but it is still only for Drupal 6.

You could try to update or improve it.

Comment: The 6 version is also a dev version and I don't see maintainers upgrading it soon.