# I want to save files directly in Drupal database, is there any solution?

Tags: database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FileField Database](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/filefield-database)

I use Drupal7 with SQL Server Driver for database and I need to save files to db directly. (not directory), convert images to binary code and save them to database maybe a solution? hoom?

Comment: Why do you need to do that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662488/would-you-store-binary-data-in-database-or-in-file-system

Comment: While the linked dup has an accepted answer, it still doesn't address Drupal 7.  @Behzan also mentions using SQL Server, while the linked questioner is using MySQL.